# Can R achieve histogram and statistics together as Eviews

Tags: r

I am new in learning R. I know in Eviews, people could get histogram and statistics in one figure. The outcome is as following
[image]

that is very convenient and beautiful. I dont want to individually do a `hist()` and statistics.

Answer (score 1):

You write a function:

```
histstat = function(x){
  hist(x)
  print(summary(x))
}

histstat(runif(1000))
```

The stats are output as text, but there are ways of putting them on the graphics device if you need output for publication like the screenshot. Most people are quite happy with text output though.

Comment: Hi spacedman, I am confused what is "histstat(runif(1000))" ?

Comment: `runif(1000)` generates just 1000 uniformly distributed numbers which are the argument of the function `histstat`.

Comment: Yes. replace `runif(1000)` with the name of your data. `histstat(mydata)` or something. Read a few introductory R tutorials and get a bigger flavour of the system.